# Displaying data from json file to react-native picker items

Tags: arrays, json, react-native

I can't for the life of me figure out how to map my list of cars to picker items.
I need it so that when the user selects the year, only car makes of that year come up, then when the users selects a make only models from that make of that year come up and then same with the engine. **Here's some of my JSON file:**
`

```
{
    "years": [
        {
            "None": {
                "None": {
                    "None": [
                        "None"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "2018": {
                "Acura": {
                    "ILX": [
                        "2.4L"
                    ],
                    "MDX": [
                        "3.5L"
                    ],
                    "MDX SH-AWD": [
                        "3.5L"
                    ],
                    "MDX Sport Hybrid": [
                        "3.0L"
                    ],
                    "RDX": [
                        "3.5L"
                    ],
                    "RLX": [
                        "3.5L"
                    ],
                    "RLX Sport Hybrid SH-AWD": [
                        "3.5L"
                    ],
                    "TLX": [
                        "2.4L",
                        "3.5L"
                    ],
                    "TLX SH-AWD": [
                        "3.5L"
                    ]
                },
                "Alfa Romeo": {
                    "4C": [
                        "1.7L"
                    ],
                    "4C Spider": [
                        "1.7L"
                    ],
                    "Giulia": [
                        "2.0L"
                    ],
                    "Giulia Quadrifoglio": [
                        "2.9L"
                    ],
                    "Giulia TI": [
                        "2.0L"
                    ],
                    "Stelvio": [
                        "2.0L"
                    ],
                    "Stelvio Quadrifoglio": [
                        "2.9L"
                    ],
                    "Stelvio TI": [
                        "2.0L"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

`
**Here is some of my react-native code at the moment:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, AsyncStorage, Picker } from 'react-native';

import { Foot } from '../../../components/Foot';
import carList from '../../../resources/test.json';

export default class AddCar extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: typeof (navigation.state.params) === 'undefined' || typeof (navigation.state.params.title) === 'undefined' ? '' : navigation.state.params.title,
        headerRight: <View></View>
    });
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hasLoaded: false,

            name: '',

            cars: [],

            Year: 'None',
            Make: 'None',
            Model: 'None',
            Engine: 'None',
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._loadInitialState().done();
    }

    _loadInitialState = async () => {

        var user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
        if (user !== null) {
            const UserInfo = JSON.parse(user);

            this.setState({ name: UserInfo['name'] });

            this.props.navigation.setParams({ title: this.state.name });
        }

        this._getCarList().done();

    }

    _getCarList = async () => {
        this.setState({ cars: carList });
        console.log(this.state.cars);
        this.setState({ hasLoaded: true });

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={styles.container}>

                <ScrollView>

                    <View style={styles.content}>

                        <View style={styles.selector}>
                            <Text style={styles.label}>Year:</Text>
                            <View style={styles.dropContainer}>
                                {this.state.hasLoaded &&
                                    <Picker
                                        style={styles.dropdown}
                                        selectedValue={this.state.Year}
                                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ Year: itemValue })} >
                                        {this.state.cars.map((item, value) => {
                                            console.log(item + " " + value);
                                            return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={value} key={value} />)
                                        })}
                                    </Picker>
                                }
                            </View>
                        </View>

                        <View style={styles.selector}>
                            <Text style={styles.label}>Make:</Text>
                            <View style={styles.dropContainer}>
                                <Picker style={styles.dropdown}
                                    selectedValue={this.state.Make}
                                    onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({ Make: itemValue })} >

                                </Picker>
                            </View>
                        </View>

                        <View style={styles.selector}>
                            <Text style={styles.label}>Model:</Text>
                            <View style={styles.dropContainer}>
                                <Picker style={styles.dropdown}
                                    selectedValue={this.state.Model}
                                    onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({ Model: itemValue })} >

                                </Picker>
                            </View>
                        </View>

                        <View style={styles.selector}>
                            <Text style={styles.label}>Engine:</Text>
                            <View style={styles.dropContainer}>
                                <Picker style={styles.dropdown}
                                    selectedValue={this.state.Model}
                                    onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({ Model: itemValue })} >
                                    <Picker.Item label="None" value="None" />
                                </Picker>
                            </View>
                        </View>

                    </View>

                </ScrollView>

                <Foot />
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: '100%',
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    },
    content: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        position: 'relative',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        marginTop: '18%',
    },
    selector: {
        width: '65%',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginTop: 5,
        padding: 3,
    },
    label: {
        flex: .35,
        fontSize: 16,
        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
        textAlign: 'left',
        top: 15,
    },
    dropContainer: {
        flex: .65,
        width: 20,
        borderColor: '#F0F0F0',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 2,
        elevation: 3,
        backgroundColor: '#FEFEFE',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the json in an object called cars you can get all years with

```
var flattenedCars = cars["years"].reduce((current, next) => { return Object.assign(current, next);})
var years = Object.keys(flattenedCars);
```

at which point you can also find the year you want with

```
cars['years'].find((car) => car[2018] != null);
```

where 2018 should be a variable.

This should lead you the rest of the way.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfect, only extra bit I added is when I map I reversed the array.